# Angular 8, multiple different animations on multiple different elements at the same time

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, animation

I have a div with some contents of which I need to animate its position, and so far so good. But another element inside that div also needs its own animation, separate from the main one. the problem is that when I try to create two different animations for it, using the same trigger, the first animation works, but the second animation doesn't animate and only skips to it's final position after the first animation has completed.

this is my HTML file:

```
<div [@moveAvatar]='state' class="contents">

  <ngx-avatar class="avatar" src="./assets/image.jpg" size="80"></ngx-avatar>

  <div class="text" [@moveText]='state'>
    <h1 class="titel"> title</h1>
    <p class="subtitel">subtitle</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

and my typescript:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  animations: [

    trigger('moveAvatar', [
      state('maximum', style({
        top: '15%',
        left: '80%',
        textAlign: 'right',
      })),
      transition('* => maximum', animate('1s ease-in-out')),
    ]),

    trigger('moveText', [
      state('maximum', style({
        top: '10%',
        left: '90%',
        transform: 'translate(-100px, -75px)',
      })),
      transition('* => maximum', animate('1s ease-in-out')),
    ])

  ]
})
```

currently this is what the two animations look like:
[image]

what am I doing wrong?

**P.S.**
I assume textAlign cannot be animated? as you can see it's included but it jumps too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

solution: use one trigger with a group() inside of it:

```
trigger('moveAvatar', [
      transition('* => maximum', [
        group([
          animate('800ms ease-in-out',
            style({
              top: '15%',
              left: '90%',
            })
          ),
          query('.text', [
            animate('800ms ease-in-out',
              style({
                top: '10%',
                left: '90%',
                transform: 'translate(-170px, -75px)',
              })
            ),
          ]),
          query('.titel', [
            animate('1s ease-in-out',
              style({
                transform: 'translate(50px, 0)',
              })
            ),
          ])
        ])
      ])
    ])
```